# Calling a Structur Pointer error: "expected a identifier.."

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am trying to get a little test program running, but now I am stuck at a very weird point. I think it is a simple problem with the structure handling but I cannot find the reason for the error. I have marked in the short example at the bottom of the post the lines with error.

main.c

```
#include "init.h"

void function1(void)
{
    xQueueReceive(handle, &( pxRxedMessage ), ( TickType_t ) 10 );      //expected expression before ')' token
    printf("%u\n", pxRxedMessage->usr_loop_cfg);
}
```

init.c

```
#include "init.h"

struct AMessage
{
    uint8_t usr_loop_cfg;
};


void create(void)
{
    xQueue = xQueueCreate( 10, sizeof( struct AMessage * ) );       
    xMessage.usr_loop_cfg = 0x40;       // Error: error: expected identifier or '(' before '=' token
    pxMessage = & xMessage;
    xQueueSend( xQueue, ( void * ) &pxMessage, ( TickType_t ) 0 );
}
```

init.h

```
#include "queue.h"

extern void create(void);

typedef struct AMessage xMessage;

typedef struct AMessage *pxRxedMessage;

typedef struct AMessage *pxMessage;
```

Comment: In `xMessage.usr_loop_cfg = 0x40;`  the `xMessage` is a *type* not a variable.

Comment: Overall this is sloppy code. Why do you suddenly use `#include <init.h>`? What is `function1(void)`? Did you bother counting parenthesis? And so on.

Comment: you are right, i tryied to tie it into a short example but made some mistakes.. sorry, i will prepare it right the next time :)

Comment: function1 one is receiving the "pxRxedMessage"

Comment: how do i have to call xmessage in this case?

Comment: @Bernd it's totally unclear what you want to do, therefore we can't answer. Maybe it's time to start reading your C text book.

Comment: @Michael Walz You were right, i just have to read the C text book

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've confused `typedef` with something that declares variables. This line for example

```
typedef struct AMessage xMessage;
```

is not creating a variable called `xMessage`. It's creating a new datatype `xMessage` that is an alias for `struct AMessage`.

If you want a variable you'd write

```
xMessage my_message;
```

or

```
struct AMessage my_message;
```

You also need to move the definition for `struct AMessage` into your header file - it needs to be visible to any code where you use `xMessage`.

Comment: ohh, thank you very much :) 
i misunderstood what my colleague was saying yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

`expected expression before ')' token`

One to many `)` in your `function1(void)`

```
receive(handle, &( pxRxedMessage ), ( TickType_t ) 10 );
```

Comment: oh sorry, this was just an typing failure of the short example here

Comment: @Bernd so you retype your code(!?). Ever head about copy/paste?

Comment: if i post the code it will be a huge post here, the question is about the structure handling, i don't think the rest of the  code is interesting

Comment: the whole code is about xQueueReceive of an LPC project with a FreeRTOS and a Queue to implement :)